# React native 0.62.0 Build is failing on Xcode 13.1

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to run my project to Xcode 13.1 but the problem is that build is failing with message:

```
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening Ajman.xcworkspace. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace Ajman.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme Ajman -destination id=6C41B609-DA05-4FAD-98F3-CC0264871189

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

note: Using new build system
note: Planning
Analyze workspace

Create build description
Build description signature: 1552deb311feffa24b258a2f780d63f1
Build description path: /Users/younisrahman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ajman-gmdogtmpvnnzkcfzhirvzdbwaslh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/1552deb311feffa24b258a2f780d63f1-desc.xcbuild

note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in parallel
CompileC /Users/younisrahman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ajman-gmdogtmpvnnzkcfzhirvzdbwaslh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTTurboModuleManager.o /Volumes/Software/Projects/React-Native/Ajman/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/turbomodule/core/platform/ios/RCTTurboModuleManager.mm normal x86_64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'ReactCommon' from project 'Pods')
    cd /Volumes/Software/Projects/React-Native/Ajman/ios/Pods
    export LANG\=en_US.US-ASCII
.
.
.
.
.
The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/younisrahman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ajman-gmdogtmpvnnzkcfzhirvzdbwaslh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTTurboModuleManager.o /Volumes/Software/Projects/React-Native/Ajman/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/turbomodule/core/platform/ios/RCTTurboModuleManager.mm normal x86_64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'ReactCommon' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
# Add this code  bottom in Podfile
post_install do |installer|
  #Fix after updating to Xcode 13.1
  find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/React/CxxBridge/RCTCxxBridge.mm",
 "_initializeModules:(NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)modules", "_initializeModules:(NSArray<Class> *)modules")
 find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/turbomodule/core/platform/ios/RCTTurboModuleManager.mm",
 "RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(module))", "RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(Class(module)))")
end

def find_and_replace(dir, findstr, replacestr)
 Dir[dir].each do |name|
     text = File.read(name)
     replace = text.gsub(findstr,replacestr)
     if text != replace
         puts "Fix: " + name
         File.open(name, "w") { |file| file.puts replace }
         STDOUT.flush
     end
 end
 Dir[dir + '*/'].each(&method(:find_and_replace))
end

# If not work try this 
change a parameter cast in the React module RCTTurboModuleManager.mm,

RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(strongModule))

to

RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(Class(strongModule)))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: did this solution work?

Comment: @SufyanSalim Yes, This is worked for me